# How to determine spacing and padding on the side of this banner?

Tags: print-design, illustration, critique, design-principles, designers

Please see the image. The yellow arrows are spaces/paddings I'm talking about.

If I use the height of my logo (bottom right corner) for all measurements, then this tag and even logo appears little too close to edges. So currently I'm using little more space than the height of logo.

How do you usually determine them? Is there any rule that will eventually make it better or it is just opinion based and can be done what looks better?

[image]

Also, I needed the big hashtag. I randomly chose a font size. Should it also follow a rule like 70% of the total width or something like that?

PS: The reason for asking this question is that last time Scott *fixed* my design by using a method for properly placing an object on design. So I think there might be a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all really personal preference and design aesthetic.. there are **no rules**.

---

I'd use the logo as the basis for spacing...

[image]

The logo is used to determine the hight of the hashtag.
Then the size of the hashtag is rotated 90° to determine position of the text.

[image]

This would be my preferred configuration.

Hashtags do not *have* to be "big". If it's readable, it's readable. There is certainly *no* readability issue with the hashtag here. The larger you make something, the more the connotation of SCREAMING is conveyed. If you do not wish to be loud, offensive, and "in-your-face", then larger is **never** better.

---

I cant read it, but I seriously *doubt* that text needs to entirely be italic. I'd personally prefer to use not italics for a single sentence. Italics are meant to be used for *emphasis*. In this usage they are merely a *distraction*.

Comment: lol do you even know what's written on it? :P Actually it's a Urdu poetry which kind of says "Before the postman comes, I must write another letter to my lover because I know what would he/she eventually reply". I replaced the Postman with Mail, lover with HR Manager, letter with Resume. Berozgar is a word for Unemployed.

Comment: @Vikas it doesn't *really* matter what it reads. I'm looking at it aesthetically.

Comment: Did you also use the height X for vertical space between logo and bottom edge of banner? It looks little less than X.

Comment: All the green boxed are the size of the logo (X) - made one around the logo and then copied. Any apparent size difference is merely a visual anomaly in the image posting.. they are all identical.

Comment: Oh okay. I thought you edited the space as well.

Comment: No no. Kindly clarify. Didn't get. Because both concepts can be right. The green mark has more width than height. So in your current concept, you would use less height between logo/berozgar and bottom edge as compared to space between side edge and logo? Or you would use same height as width (it's just because you didn't have much space to place the green mark)?

Comment: I used the dimensions of the logo... it is not symmetrical, therefore the spacing isn't symmetrical. The hashtag/logo sit above the bottom edge the same distance as the logo is tall. They sit from the left/right edge the same width as the logo. The green boxes are *not* meant to be "squares" because the logo is not defined by a square.

Comment: I used italic because it's not very serious text, it's poetry and it's just a kind of intriguing *campaign* for awareness.

Comment: Regarding logo height. There are at least 3 options *really*. Make the height of *small letters* (e.g. e, a, o) height same as logo or make the height of b, # or g same as logo or make overall height including parts of b small letter and g same as logo height. I think you meant the *small letters* as reference because that covers most part of hashtag?

Comment: Also, the length of hashtag as position of text has a downside. The text now comes little lower to vertical center of banner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102900/discussion-between-vikas-and-scott).

Answer (score 1):

Every designer has his/her own methods, but generally yes I'd say go with whatever looks good.

I personally don't believe in rules much and design things to just look well spaced out, unless there's a very specific branding guidelines document to follow.

In your particular case, it looks like there's plenty of space at the top of the banner, so why not move the logo up, then move the hashtag about 2 times <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, 2 times <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and make it 10-15% bigger font size.

[image]

Comment: Does 2-shift have special meaning?

Comment: Presumably you're using Adobe software, and in all these a SHIFT+ARROW will move items by a predefined amount. You can also read this as "20 pixels up and 20 pixels to the right", but the actual amount can be edited via preferences.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: The hashtag is coming close to logo after making changes as you suggested. And you said move logo up only. While the hashtag is moved up and on right. So there's different horizontal space around edges of banner and hashtag and logo. I think logo should also be 2-shift left then?